# What is the best way to version software builds by using GIT repo (MAJOR.MINOR.COMMIT_NUMBER)?

Tags: git, jenkins, svn, build, artifacts

I am using Jenkins to run builds and run tests. I am in process of migration from SVN to Git.
Currently, I version software using MAJOR.MINOR.SVN_REVISION format.

For example, the MAJOR and MINOR is coming from the pom.xml for Java projects and libraries

```
...
<groupId>com.example.ci</groupId>
<artifactId>test-java-project</artifactId>
<version>2.1</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
...
```

When the Java application/software is built I add the SVN revision to the version.
For example, if the SVN revision of the build is 123 then the full version will be 2.1.123. This works great.

I can't use the same logic for Git because Git commit number is a hash number and it is not sequential.
For example: 2.1.a126ac21090

This will cause issues when I need to identify the latest libraries and applications by using the version number.

**The first option** is to use the Jenkins build number (MAJOR.MINOR.JENKINS_BUILD_NUMBER) but this also has some drawbacks like having a production and staging Jenkins producing the same version number for two different artifacts.

**The second option** is to use "git rev-list --count" but this could return the same number for two distinct feature branches and I could end up with two different artifacts having the same version number.

Is there another better way to version software similar to MAJOR.MINOR.SVN_REVISION using Git?

Answer (score 0):

You still can keep your label, but also generate a property file with the Git revision ID.

See [`git-commit-id/maven-git-commit-id-plugin`](https://github.com/git-commit-id/maven-git-commit-id-plugin) as an example of a Maven plugin which will automate that process.
See [Maven central](https://search.maven.org/artifact/pl.project13.maven/git-commit-id-plugin/2.2.5/maven-plugin).

> Maven plugin which includes build-time git repository information into an POJO / `*.properties`).
>   Make your apps tell you which version exactly they were built from!

Comment: Yes, this works only if you need to save and have the revision number in the properties file but as I know this will not work if you upload the artifact to Artifactory and want to get the latest.

Comment: I have been working with Artifactory for the past two years. It does work just fine, considering Artifactory will use the classic GAV. The properties file is a complement to that ID, that you can query at runtime.